# Angular app not working after ngForm is added

Tags: angular

I am trying to connect an Angular-App to an Api. My problem is my form in Angular. It seems to break the whole app when using ngForm in my form

I have deleted all ngForms from my form then my app seems to work again.

Here is my working code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form >
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" >
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="FirstName" >
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="LastName">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="DateOfBirth" >
    </div> ...
</form>
```

Here is the code that destroys everything

```html
<div class="container">
  <form #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" #Id="ngModel" ngModel[(ngModel)]="service.formData.Id">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="FirstName" #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.FirstName" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="FirstName.invalid && FirstName.touched">Dieses Feld muss ausgefüllt sein</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="LastName" #LastName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.LastName" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="LastName.invalid && LastName.touched">Dieses Feld muss ausgefüllt sein</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="DateOfBirth" #DateOfBirth="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="FirstName.invalid && FirstName.touched">Dieses Feld muss ausgefüllt sein</div>
    </div>
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. Especially because when adding all the clutter to my form I does not only break the output of this html but I breaks all output. All I get after inserting the ngForm-stuff is a blank page.
Also it also breaks when I just add the form tag with all its parameters without the input-tags inside of it.

Comment: Hi! Do you have any messages in the console? Be sure to include them to help us understand what is causing the error!

Comment: `ngModel[(ngModel)]`: That's not valid. There might be other errors. Post the error you get in the console. It's meant to be read.

Comment: Also I see a typo on line #3 : `ngModel[(ngModel)]`, that could be it?

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback the ngModel[(ngModel)] was the problem. I was very confused, because I did not get any error message for me it was a needle in a haystack (still a beginner). Thanks for your feedback guys.

Comment: Can you try to recreate the problem in StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ngModel[(ngModel)] is not  correct. Hope this will help.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" #Id="ngModel" ngModel[(ngModel)]="service.formData.Id">
```

I have a doubt is there is a requirement of this hidden input field? I think you can easily manage the id filed in .ts file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the Id field. I am still learning, let's say I was heavily inspired by a tutorial where someone did it with this hidden id input.